# WAMP VirtualHost 403

Tags: apache, virtualhost, 403-forbidden, permissions

I recently installed WAMP, and started developing on its Apache server. Given that my text editor (Sublime) didn't have permissions to write on C disk directly, I changed my default DocumentRoot to `My Docs/www` and everything was working fine (except that any site with `.htaccess` did not work).

I decided then to make virtual Hosts to solve this problem, but even `localhost` returns a 403 (and everything else).

Anyone knows why and how to reconfigure everything? (or how to give Sublime rights?)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what Apache version your WAMP is using, you may need to replace these directives in your regular virtual host settings:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

with

```
Require all granted
```

Please see more about upgrading form Apache 2.2 to Apache 2.4 [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/upgrading.html).

Answer (score 0):

I had the 403 error and this bit solved it.

```
Require all granted
```

I was almost ready to give up on virtual hosts with Wamp. Although I had read 2-3 blogs I missed this option. Also on my browser it was using google search in URL bar so I had to type http:// before the server name the first time I typed it.